# Little bit error in print text in file using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am writing some text in csv file using python.. 
Here is the screenshot of that in which way i am getting write data in file.
[image]

You can see that in Channel Social Media Links column all the links are writing well in other next line cell but first link is not writing in Channel Social Media Links column. Please how can i write like this?
[image]

My python script is here

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myUrl='https://www.youtube.com/user/HolaSoyGerman/about'


uClient = uReq(myUrl)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("h1",{"class":"branded-page-header-title"})

filename="Products2.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")

headers = "Channel Name,Channel Description,Channel Social Media Links\n"

f.write(headers)

channel_name = containers[0].a.text 
print("Channel Name :" + channel_name)

# For About Section Info
aboutUrl='https://www.youtube.com/user/HolaSoyGerman/about'


uClient1 = uReq(aboutUrl)
page_html1 = uClient1.read()
uClient1.close()

page_soup1 = soup(page_html1, "html.parser")

description_div = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"about-description 
branded-page-box-padding"})
channel_description = description_div[0].pre.text
print("Channel Description :" + channel_description)
f.write(channel_name+ "," +channel_description)
links = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"channel-links-item"})
for link in links: 
social_media = link.a.get("href")
f.write(","+","+social_media+"\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: You don't include a newline after `f.write(channel_name+ "," +channel_description)`, so of course the first line will be further over. Also, note that `"," + "," == ",,"`, and that the CSV module supports writing from a sequence rather than adding commas yourself.

Comment: so how can i achieve this please give me example. i want social media links not separated by comma. i want that in Social Media links all the links should be write in new next line cell of Social Media Links Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you made use of Python's CSV library when writing to your file. This is able to convert a list of items into correctly comma separated values.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

myUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/HolaSoyGerman/about'

uClient = uReq(myUrl)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("h1",{"class":"branded-page-header-title"})
filename = "Products2.csv"

with open(filename, "w", newline='') as f:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f)
    headers = ["Channel Name", "Channel Description", "Channel Social Media Links"]
    csv_output.writerow(headers)

    channel_name = containers[0].a.text 
    print("Channel Name :" + channel_name)

    # For About Section Info
    aboutUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/HolaSoyGerman/about'

    uClient1 = uReq(aboutUrl)
    page_html1 = uClient1.read()
    uClient1.close()

    page_soup1 = soup(page_html1, "html.parser")

    description_div = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"about-description branded-page-box-padding"})
    channel_description = description_div[0].pre.text
    print("Channel Description :" + channel_description)

    links = [link.a.get('href') for link in page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"channel-links-item"})]
    csv_output.writerow([channel_name, channel_description, links[0]])

    for link in links[1:]:
        csv_output.writerow(['', '', link])
```

This would give you a single row with each of the hrefs in the last column, for example:

```
Channel Name,Channel Description,Channel Social Media Links
HolaSoyGerman.,Los Hombres De Verdad Usan Pantuflas De Perrito,http://www.twitter.com/germangarmendia
,,http://instagram.com/germanchelo
,,http://www.youtube.com/juegagerman
,,http://www.youtube.com/juegagerman
,,http://www.twitter.com/germangarmendia
,,http://instagram.com/germanchelo
,,https://plus.google.com/108460714456031131326
```

Each `writerow()` call will write a list of values to the file as comma separated values and automatically add the newline for you at the end. All that is needed is to build the lists of values for each row. First of all  take the first of your links and make it the last value in the list after your channel description. Secondly, write a row for each remaining link where the first two columns have blank values.

---

To answer your comment, the following should get you started:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

def get_data(url, csv_output):

    if not url.endswith('/about'):
        url += '/about'

    print("URL: {}".format(url))
    uClient = uReq(url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("h1", {"class":"branded-page-header-title"})

    channel_name = containers[0].a.text 
    print("Channel Name :" + channel_name)

    description_div = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"about-description branded-page-box-padding"})
    channel_description = description_div[0].pre.text
    print("Channel Description :" + channel_description)

    links = [link.a.get('href') for link in page_soup.findAll("li", {"class":"channel-links-item"})]
    csv_output.writerow([channel_name, channel_description, links[0]])

    for link in links[1:]:
        csv_output.writerow(['', '', link])

    #TODO - get list of links for the related channels

    return related_links


my_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/HolaSoyGerman'
filename = "Products2.csv"

with open(filename, "w", newline='') as f:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f)
    headers = ["Channel Name", "Channel Description", "Channel Social Media Links"]
    csv_output.writerow(headers)

    for _ in range(5):
        next_links = get_data(my_url, csv_output)
        my_url = next_links[0]      # e.g. follow the first of the related links
```

Comment: i am fetching information from youtube's channel using web scraping and saving it in csv file. now i want that when any youtube's channel information has fetched in csv file then automatically from  "Related Channel" section first channel's url will fetch in a variable and then again whole process should be done and it goes on for 5 times.  how can i do this?

Comment: I would say that is a rather different question. You would need to explain it better with an example. If my answer has solved your first question, I suggest you accept the solution (click on the grey tick under the up/down button) and then start a more detailed second question with more details.

Comment: I want following flow of my script

Comment: I want following flow of my script
1) Grab information(Name, Social Media Links, Description) from youtube's channel (I hard code the url of youtube channel for the first time to pull information)
2) Grab another channel url from "Related Channels" section and again repeat step 1 and repeate these steps 5 times. 
I have done first step with hard code url but now i want second step. how can i do this?

Comment: I'll try and have a look in the next day or so.

Comment: can u have a look now? because i have to submit this task tomorrow morning :/

Comment: Sorry have time tonight to complete it, but I have given you an idea on how to progress. I have added the start of solution to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150031/discussion-between-fahad-subzwari-and-martin-evans).